# AWS Linux: run iptable command upon machine boot

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services

I want need to run this command everytime the instance (AWS Linux) is booted.

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3000
```

I couldn't find back the tutorial that register this command into linux file. It would be great if anyone can provide the references.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo  /sbin/service iptables save`

See (the AWS standard images are redhat-derived):

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security_Guide/sect-Security_Guide-IPTables-Saving_IPTables_Rules.html